# GET requests aren't returning from SimpleHTTPServer

Tags: python, windows

I'm trying to host an HTML document over Python's SimpleHTTPServer, and I'm having a bit of trouble.

The server works fine locally. I can access my document at localhost:8000/test.html.

However, when I try to access the document from my phone (at http://xx.xxx.xx.xx:8000/test.html), it doesn't work. The strange thing is that I can see the GET request being logged by SimpleHTTPServer:

```
C:\Users\[...]\Documents\test>python -m SimpleHTTPServer
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000 ...
xx.xxx.xx.xx - - [24/Jun/2014 15:20:12] "GET /test.html HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

It looks exactly the same as the request from localhost, except for the IP address. But it's not returning.

This seems like an issue with Windows Firewall, but I'm a bit stumped as to how that could be. I've added rules to allow all inbound and outbound connections for python.exe, over TCP and UDP for inbound, and over all protocols for outbound, and it's still not working. I've even turned the firewall off entirely, and the same thing happens.

Any suggestions?

Comment: First turn off firewall and test it without firewall.

Comment: Good call. It doesn't seem to make a difference, though.

Comment: Maybe you have some hardware (router, access point) with firewall/filter.

Comment: I don't think so, everything is connected to my own virtual router.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whoops, I was connecting through the wrong router, and getting firewalled. I'm not sure how my phone managed to do that, but, well, problem solved?

Comment: Sometimes hardware and software can suprise us :)